# Routing Problem - Display page not found in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have this code in my Laravel-5.8 application:

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Appraisal;

class AppraisalRespondentsController extends Controller
{
    public function proceedrespondent()
    {
        return View::make('appraisal.appraisal_respondents.proceedrespondent');
    }
}
```

appraisal->appraisal_respondents->proceedrespondent

route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'appraisal', 'as' => 'appraisal.', 'namespace' => 'Appraisal', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

    Route::get('appraisal_respondents/proceedrespondent', 'AppraisalRespondentsController@proceedrespondent')->name('appraisal_respondents.proceedrespondent');

}
```

When I click on this

```
 <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route("appraisal.appraisal_respondents.proceedrespondent") }}">
    Display
 </a>
```

to render the page. I got this error:

```
404  Not Found.  Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. Go Back
```

This is my **route:list**:

```
| GET|HEAD     | appraisal/appraisal_respondents/proceedrespondent     | appraisal.appraisal_respondents.proceedrespondent    | App\Http\Controllers\Appraisal\AppraisalRespondentsController@proceedrespondent                        | web,auth           |
```

How do I resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: what the url is in browser?

Comment: I assume that when you `dd(route("appraisal.appraisal_respondents.proceedrespondent"))`, it does return `/appraisal/appraisal_respondents/proceedrespondent`?

Comment: Use `<a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route("appraisal_respondents/proceedrespondent") }}">`

Comment: This is the url in the browser   http://localhost:8888/myapp/appraisal/appraisal_respondents/proceedrespondent

Comment: remove your 'namespace' => 'Appraisal'

Answer (score 0):

Just use the route name

```
 <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ 
 route("appraisal_respondents.proceedrespondent") }}">
    Display
</a>
```

Comment: When I did as you advised, I got this error:   production.ERROR: Route [appraisal_respondents.proceedrespondent] not defined

Comment: How about <a class="btn btn-info" href="/appraisal/appraisal_respondents/proceedrespondent">
    Display
 </a>

Comment: production.ERROR: Route [/appraisal/appraisal_respondents/proceedrespondent] not defined

Comment: <a class="btn btn-info" href="appraisal/appraisal_respondents/proceedrespondent"> Display </a>

Comment: It shows Error 404, not found   It now added another appraisal        http://localhost:8888/myapp/appraisal/appraisal/appraisal_respondents/proceedrespondent

Comment: <a class="btn btn-info" href="appraisal_respondents/proceedrespondent"> Display </a>